# Removing index.php AND the subdirectory folder name

Tags: htaccess

I'm developing a site at the moment and noticed when I uploaded it to my staging server, all my links show correctly in the address bar, but show the index template.

My folder structure is as follows

```
/
  /pub
    index.php
    .htaccess
  /system
  /templates
  .htaccess
```

My site runs inside /pub - Because I'm not able to specify with my host what the root directory of a site should be, they've advised that I use htaccess instead.

That .htaccess file sits in / and looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage.domain.co$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.stage.domain.co$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !pub/
RewriteRule (.*) /pub/$1 [L]
```

I also have a .htaccess file in /pub/ which looks like this:

```
# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[^/]*/index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.+) $1 [R=301,L]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

I want to remove index.php, AND the pub directory so my site will serve up URLs such as stage.domain.com/exercises instead of stage.domain.com/pub/index.php/exercises

So two questions..
Should I be using two htaccess files like I am at the moment, one to redirect from /pub/, and one to remove index.php, or should they be in one file, and where should it be?

What needs to be in those files to make it work?! I've tried what EE suggested by removing the slash before index.php on the last line, and adding a question mark.

Comment: Are you sure that the /pub folder doesn't map to the root of your website - that's the norm.  It would be really weird to have your site start example.com/pub.  If so then you just need the standard .htaccess to removed index.php

Comment: That's what I WANT to happen, but no. If I remove the first htaccess file, you can only access the site through domain.co/pub. If you go to domain.co, you get a directory listing the same as I put in my question. I had to put the first htaccess file in because my hosting company won't let me specify the root directory.

Comment: Surely I can't be the only person who's host won't let them change their root directory?

Comment: why not just move everything 1 level up?

Comment: I can't add anything the the directory above my root.

Comment: sure but having the website served from /pub and the system folder above that isn't any more secure because people still have access to that folder because it's publicly accessible. My suggestion would be rename the system folder (and admin.php) and disable directory listing via htaccess with Options -Indexes

Comment: Thanks for your information Steven - You're right, hadn't thought of that. However, thanks to some helpful pointers from the hosting company, I've managed to get it set up so I can now add directories above the /public_html folder, so I only have to deal with rewriting the index.php, which I know how to do.
(Not sure if I should be marking this as an answer or removing the question).

Comment: Have you tried rewriting the base?

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pub

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing doesn't make any sense. There is no point having a separate `/pub` directory if everything is still within the webroot.

The only reason you would have a separate `pub` (or `public_html`) directory is if you want to keep your system folder above the webroot. This adds an extra layer of security, though it only really protects against a misconfigured apache and isn't really worth the extra work on shared servers IMO.

Just move your `index.php` and `.htaccess` out of `/pub`, and stick to the convention:

```
/
  /system
  /templates
  .htaccess
  index.php
```

To remove `/index.php/` from your URLs, just follow [Removing index.php from URLs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/remove_index.php.html), so your htaccess should look like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```